# Writing to text file are appearing in Chinese when the read file is in english

Tags: c++

Can someone tell me what is wrong with this program? It should read from an input file and write to an output file. It will use '.' as an indicator that the line has ended.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    const int LENGTH = 250;
    char in[LENGTH];
    std::ifstream inFile;
    std::ofstream outFile;
    char ch;

    inFile.open("infile.txt");
    if (inFile.fail())
    {
        std::cout << "Error no file";
        exit(1);
    }

    outFile.open("outfile.txt", std::ios::out);
    while (!inFile.fail())
    {
        int count = 1;
        inFile.getline(in, LENGTH);
        ch = toupper(in[0]);
        outFile << ch;
        std::cout << ch;

        while (!(ch == '.'))
        {
            ch = in[count];
            outFile << ch;
            std::cout << ch;
            outFile.flush();
            count++;
        }
    }

    inFile.close();
    outFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code, the output file is full of Chinese characters. When display to `cout` it seems to display it correctly minus the formatting issues, I guess when it is written to file, the stream is not flushing and just combining the ASCII numbers together.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_hid_the_facts

Comment: To ease the OP a bit, this is also relevant: http://www.hoax-slayer.com/bush-hid-the-facts-notepad.html :P ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
while (!(ch == '.'))
```

will make you read beyond the char array in, and cause stackoverflow.

To fix this issue, try to replace this line with

```
while (ch != 0)
```

You should rely on the 0(ascii '\0') to check the terminal for a C string, not the character '.'